# Current context for get set method using System.Activities.InArgument<string>

Tags: c#, .net

short question. I want to define a get set method for an `InArgument<string>`
Looks like that:

[image]

What do I have to use for the `System.Activities.ActivityContext` argument of the get method?

Thanks...

Comment: Try `Get<string>`.

Comment: One still needs the ActivityContext....